# Eclipse Kepler CDT - Symbol 'HWND' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I went through a small tutorial on creating GUIs with C++.
http://www.jose.it-berater.org/smfforum/index.php?PHPSESSID=1f234ca7a3e61aebeeaae8b8f73a7125&topic=3389.msg14548#msg14548

When I tried it out with Eclipse Kepler CDT I only got lots of Errors shown in the Editor which all sounded same:
Type 'CALLBACK' could not be resolved.
Type 'HWND' could not be resolved.
[...]

What have I done wrong? I have just copied the Sourcecode mentioned in this Tutorial...

Comment: I would guess you missed `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: I included windows.h, tchar.h and stdio.h exactly like in the tutorial.